# Trouble understanding Latin squares and group theory

Tags: group-theory, latin-square, cayley-table

This is more of a theoretical question, but I'm having trouble understanding why it is that Latin squares are generalizations of a group?

I kind of arrived at this question trying to figure out why independent vectors were so important in linear algebra.

To phrase the question differently, why are groups composed of a set *n* with *n* objects and *n* permutations?

Comment: @DietrichBurde The multiplication table of a finite group is a latin square.

Comment: Not every latin square is the multiplication table of a group.

Comment: You should really say that Latin squares are a generalization of finite groups. The multiplication table determines a finite group completely. On the other hand, it is easy to form Latin squares which do not correspond to any finite group.

Comment: One can also define infinite, uncountable, even continuous quasigroups and varieties of quasigroups and loops that are not defined by a latin square but (for instance) by generators, relations and identities. For an introduction to that see for example works by J. D. H. Smith *Postmodern Algebra*, works by Mal'cev, Sabinin, etc. Lookup also *Moufang relations*, *Bol Loops*.

Answer (score 1):

To put together the two comments by Matt Samuel and jbuddenh, we can certainly claim that

> The multiplication table of a finite group is a latin square **but** not every latin square is the multiplication table of a group.

Every latin square is the multiplication table of a [quasigroup](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Quasigroup.html). A quasigroup is a magma (groupoid) $G$ where, for all $a\in G$, the left and right translation $L_a(x)$, $R_a(x)$ are bijections of $G$ (permutations). This is, a quasigroup is a magma (groupoid) $G$ with left and right cancellation and left/right division (see definitions 1 to 12 in [this paper](http://www.math.md/files/basm/y2007-n2/y2007-n2-(pp43-54).pdf)).

Among all quasigroups, only those showing associativity are groups. Hence, in front of a multiplication table that is a latin square, one must test associativity before claiming that is a group.

For example,

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
\circ & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
\hline
1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
2 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 1\\
3 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 1 & 2\\
4 & 4 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
5 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\end{array}$$

is a group while

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
\bullet & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
\hline
1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
2 & 2 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 3\\
3 & 3 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 4\\
4 & 4 & 3 & 5 & 1 & 2\\
5 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1\\
\end{array}$$

is *only* a quasigroup (with identity, $1$), although

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 1\\
3 & 4 & 5 & 1 & 2\\
4 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
5 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\end{array}
&
\text{ and }
&
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
2 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 3\\
3 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 4\\
4 & 3 & 5 & 1 & 2\\
5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1\\
\end{array}
\\
\end{array}$$

are both latin squares (reference: page 5 of [this book](https://books.google.it/books?id=MQbvAAAAMAAJ&q=quasigroups+and+loops,+introduction&dq=quasigroups+and+loops,+introduction)).

It is often thaught that a set together with a binary operation is called a *magma* or a *groupoid*, an associative groupoid is a *semigroup*, a semigroup with identity is a *monoid* and, finally, a monoid with inverses is a *group*. On the other hand, a groupoid with left/right cancellation and division is called a quasigroup and an associative quasigroup is a group ([an associative quasigroup also have identity](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Nonempty_associative_quasigroup_equals_group)).

Comment: While the last paragraph is true, it should be noted that the term "magma" is also used, and that most uses of the term groupoid refer to something altogether different.

Comment: @JHance again, true, thank you. But the use of the word _gruopoid_ is here coherent with most of the reference I cited.